# fasttext with udf pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have been trying to implement a udf in pyspark out of a py function as follows:

It takes a bin model I previously trained.

```
def sentiment(frase):
    classifier = load_model("sentiment_fasttext.bin")
    sentiment = classifier.predict(frase)
    sentiment = ''.join(map(str, sentiment))
    return sentiment

sentiment = df.withColumn('sentiment', sentiment_udf(col('input_text')))
```

The input_text column contain normal text and df its the dataframe containing the whole data.

where I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-9df3b4c420df> in <module>()
----> 1 sentiment.show()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    376         """
    377         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 378             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    379         else:
    380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o380.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 69, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 580, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fasttext'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 366, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 69, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 580, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fasttext'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

​
Fasttext is currently running and the python function runs without any problem on the same notebook.

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

Its because the object you try to serialize contains native code and hence it is not possible. You can use save_model to save it on the disk and retrieve it later.

Git issue [link](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/849)